# display alert when mouse hovers over word in text

Tags: javascript, html

I have been struggling with this for a few days. I need somebody to steer me in the right direction. I have been searching on the web. I am not sure if I took the right approach. What I need is that each time a person hovers over a particular keyword, it should display an alert box. In this example the word is else. When I run the code it does not give any errors and does not display anything when mouse hovers on the word.

```
function on_func2()
{
    var searchString = 'else';
    var elements = document.getElementById('paragraph2');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
        if (elements[i].innerHTML.indexOf(searchString) !== -1) 
        {
            alert('Match');
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `getElementById` returns one element. Did you mean to find all of that element's child nodes?

Comment: <p id="paragraph2"> <span onmouseover="on_func2()" onmouseout="off_func2()">if you were not there, else I would not have won</span></p> (when the mouse hovers the word else in this sentence)

Comment: Yes. all the element's child nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery [lettering](http://letteringjs.com/) plugin

```
<p class="word_split">if you were not there, else I would not have won.<p>


$(".word_split").lettering('words');
$('.word_split').mouseover(function(event) {
    var word=event.target.innerHTML;
    if (word == "else")
       alert("Yep");
});
```

here's a demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vN83X/)

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:
It will go through and find all `else` words, and wrap them in a span with a listener bound:

```
<p id="hello">What else would you say?</p>
```

-

```
​var hello = document.getElementById('hello');
var str = hello.innerHTML;
str = str.replace(​​​ /\b(else)\b/g, '<span onmouseover="func1()">$1</span>' );​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
hello.innerHTML = str;

function func1() {
  alert('there');
}
```

Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kDdYV/).