# Html text hover over each word for translation

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have a HTML page with a text body within it. I want to be able to hover over the words in text and a small cloud shows the translation of that word in the text. Any idea how can I do it?
i will provide the translation i need to know which is the best approach to separate each word out of text on hover and check it with a list of words or translations maybe..

```
<html>
<body text="black">
    <p>I need the code to be able to translate each word separately</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The simplest solution is to put every word inside an inline element (i.e `span`), and use some kind of tooltips. A more complex and efficient way would be to use the `mousemove` event and to somehow detect what word is being hovered and then present a tooltip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answer to this Question [display alert when mouse hovers over word in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434232/display-alert-when-mouse-hovers-over-word-in-text?rq=1).
Using the [lettering](http://letteringjs.com/) jQuery plugin you can bind events to hovers on words. if you have a dictionary or something in which you use the word as a key to find the translation you can show it in a little box above it.

Hope this helps

Majid L also made a http://jsfiddle.net/vN83X, hover over the word else

```
$(".word_split").lettering('words');
$('.word_split').mouseover(function(event) {
}
```