# javascript rollover to get text

Tags: javascript, firefox, rollover

Is it possible to use javascript in order when rolling over or (clicking) a word in a web page to get that word (e.g in variable). I would like to make a firefox extension with that feature.

Comment: Assuming you can use jQuery, you probably want something like this:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434232/display-alert-when-mouse-hovers-over-word-in-text?rq=1

Comment: @Charlie74 I think he wants a way to achieve this without having control over the page itself. e.g. an extension that would allow this to be done on any page. As far as I know, that would be difficult to achieve reliably, if at all.

Comment: @DBS agh yes, I think you're correct.   After reading again, I see the goal is an extension, which would make this page independent.

Comment: Yes it is actually about independent pages on the web, so an extension is the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ofcourse there is nothing such as clicking a word , as it is not an object , eventhough you can highlight a word , and yes you can get its value check this :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getSelection

```
function foo() {
    var selObj = window.getSelection(); 
    alert(selObj);
    var selRange = selObj.getRangeAt(0);
    // do stuff with the range
}
```

Comment: i guess that could be ok... i'll look it up.

Answer (score -1):

There is a HTML attribute which can use to get a tooltip on any element.

```
<p><abbr title="World Health Organization">WHO</abbr> was founded in 1948.</p>
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp

Comment: So many things wrong ... dangling abbr close tag, link to w3schools, and you didn't actually answer the OP's question!