# Alert when mouse is hovering over text (HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, function, mouseover

So I am writing a code that displays an alert box whenever the mouse hovers over a piece of text in HTML. The problem that I have is it is not working and I am not sure why. I tried finding help online but none of them worked. I need something that doesn't use JQuery for this assignment. What I have tried is to use function when activated with the mouse over event handler but that also didn't work.

This is my code:

```
        function mouseOver(){
            showAlert();
        }

        function showAlert(){
            alert("Alert!");
        }
```

This is another method that I have tried:

```
        function mouseOver(){
            document.getElementById("text").alert("Alert!");
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [display alert when mouse hovers over word in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434232/display-alert-when-mouse-hovers-over-word-in-text)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   function mouseOver(){
              alert("Alert!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```js
document.getElementById("text").addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {
  alert("Alert!");
}, false);
```

```html
<p id="text">Hover Me</p>
```